# How To Know if The Ground Detection is Lost in Unity Vuforia?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am facing the following issue when I am using ground plane detection:

While I am moving the mobile phone, sometimes the ground detection is lost, and this situation remains for minutes and no indicator displayed in the scene.

Is there a way to know if the Indicator is in the screen limits within the world scene?